# (Verfication )Showing existence of maximal disjointed subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is given as an exercise in Pinter's Set Theory book and I'm wondering if my work is correct:

---

> A set of sets $\mathcal{A}$ is said to be disjointed if for all $C,D
>  \in A, C \cap D=\emptyset$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set of sets; prove
> that $\mathcal{F}$ has a maximal disjointed subset.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set of sets. Let $\mathfrak{S}=\{ \mathcal{A}\in  \mathscr{P}(\mathcal{F}): (\forall C,D\in\mathcal{A})( C \cap D=\emptyset)\}$. $S$ is nonempty because $\emptyset\in S$ vacuously. Consider $\mathfrak{S}$ as a poset with inclusion as the partial order. Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be a chain in $\mathfrak{S}$. We claim that $\bigcup \mathfrak{C}$ is an element of $\mathfrak{S}$. Let $C,D \in \bigcup \mathfrak{C}$. Then $C \in \mathcal{C}$ and $D\in \mathcal{D}$ for some $\mathcal{C} \in \mathfrak{S}$ and $\mathcal{D} \in \mathfrak{S}$. Since $\mathfrak{C}$ is a chain, we may assume wlog that $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{D}$ and so $C,D \in \mathcal{D}$. So, $C\cap D=\emptyset$. Hence, by Zorn's Lemma, there must be a maximal disjointed subset.

---

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. By the way, in my experience it is more common to say that such a family of sets is *pairwise disjoint*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Such a family is called *pairwise disjoint*, more usually. And it's a property of [finite character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_character) (you check on pairs of sets) so as you rightly sketch, considering the poset of such families it's easy to verify that for a chain of such families, their union is one too. So Zorn applies etc. This special subcase of Zorn is called the [Teichmüller-Tukey lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller%E2%80%93Tukey_lemma); it's a commonly used fact, even though not often quoted as such. It also applies to finding a maximal linearly ordered subset of a poset, or a maximal independent subset of a vector space, etc.